# Amazon Web Services: Spark Streaming or Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am looking for some high level guidance on an architecture.  I have a provider writing "transactions" to a Kinesis pipe (about 1MM/day).  I need to pull those transactions off, one at a time, validating data, hitting other SOAP or Rest services for additional information, applying some business logic, and writing the results to S3.

One approach that has been proposed is use Spark job that runs forever, pulling data and processing it within the Spark environment.  The benefits were enumerated as shareable cached data, availability of SQL, and in-house knowledge of Spark.

My thought was to have a series of Lambda functions that would process the data.  As I understand it, I can have a Lambda watching the Kinesis pipe for new data.  I want to run the pulled data through a bunch of small steps (lambdas), each one doing a single step in the process.  This seems like an ideal use of Step Functions. With regards to caches, if any are needed, I thought that Redis on ElastiCache could be used.

Can this be done using a combination of Lambda and Step Functions (using lambdas)?  If it can be done, is it the best approach?  What other alternatives should I consider?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a combination of Lambda and Step Functions. As you described, the lambda would monitor the stream and kick off a new execution of a state machine, passing the transaction data to it as an input.  You can see more documentation around kinesis with lambda here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html.
The state machine would then pass the data from one Lambda function to the next where the data will be processed and written to S3. You need to contact AWS for an increase on the default 2 per second StartExecution API limit to support 1MM/day.

Hope this helps!